# How to generate a dynamic word document from a doc template in java?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx4j, jcifs

I have a word doc template where I have to fill the values dynamically from a Java object. The document template will be in the project classpath, and I will have to fill the values dynamically and save that same file to a shared folder location.

I have used JCIFS to save files to a restricted shared location. The file is created successfully, but the content is not generated correctly. Following is the code,

```
    String user = "username:pwd";
String fileName = outputTemp.docx;

NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
System.out.println("Auth =" + auth);
String path = "smb: path" + fileName;
System.out.println("SMB PATH =" + path);

String output = "Downloads\\Projctnam\\src\\main\\resources\\templates\\";

DocxStamper stamper = new DocxStamper(new DocxStamperConfiguration());
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("template.docx"));
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output+fileName);

SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
sfos.write(out.toString().getBytes());

stamper.stamp(inputStream, variables, out);

sfos.close();
out.close();
```

This is how the content is added to the file,

[image: word doc content]

The code seems to be fine for me.

Comment: What isn't working with your two bits of code?

Comment: Add your full code.

Comment: @Shakthifuture please checknow

Comment: `sfos.write(out.toString().getBytes())` is not how things work...

Comment: I have found out a way, it's working fine now

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out the way, it's working perfectly fine now

```
String user = "username:pwd";
String fileName = outputTemp.docx;

NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
System.out.println("Auth =" + auth);
String path = "smb: path" + fileName;
System.out.println("SMB PATH =" + path);

String output = "Downloads\\Projctnam\\src\\main\\resources\\templates\\";

DocxStamper stamper = new DocxStamper(new DocxStamperConfiguration());
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("template.docx"));
//OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output+fileName);

SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
//sfos.write(out.toString().getBytes());

stamper.stamp(inputStream, variables, sfos);

sfos.close();
out.close();
```